# What tense is this?

Tags: tenses

**Fun isn’t something one considers when balancing the universe. But this… does put a smile on my face.**

What tense is this, I'm really confused...

Comment: Well, first of all, you have two sentences there, with a total of three verbs.  ISTM that they are they are all the same tense, but that isn't necessarily the case for multiple sentences in a paragraph, or even multiple clauses in a sentence.  Is there any particular one that you're confused by?  What tense(s) do you think they are, and why are you confused?

Answer (score 0):

It is present tense. It is emphasised by using the auxiliary verb "to do".

*John: Does this put a smile on your face?*

*Jane: Yes, this puts a smile on my face.*

or

*Jane: Yes, this **does** put a smile on my face.* (The affirmative statement is emphasised)

Comment: And one last question if you don't mind answering, "Fun isn’t something one considers when balancing the universe." I assume this is present continous tense?